# Are there any trade offs of picking RabbitMQ over Redis as a ServiceStack MQ Broker?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

I'm in the very beginnings of designing system that will be queue based and would like to hear the pros and cons of going with one or the other as a backing store for the messages.

Rough flow of the process:

ServiceStack external web service will receive HTTP messages and send those DTOs immediately to a durable message queue. I can envision that this particular queue/topic is PubSub as I have a number of other processes that might want to be notified, one would be a process to store the message for historical reasons, another would be to act on the message itself and perform some operation... the lists subscribers/clients goes on and on.

Is there anything holding me back from implementing something along those lines, except for my very limited experience with ServiceStack and durable queue based messaging?

My reading so far have included these articles:

[Redis Persistence](http://redis.io/topics/persistence)

[Redis persistence demystified](http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html)

[ServiceStack - Messaging and Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis)

[ServiceStack - SMessageService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/Reusability%2FSMessageService.cs)

[ServiceStack - RedisMqServerTest](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Server.Tests/Messaging/RedisMqServerTests.cs#L291)

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any features in [Redis MQ](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis) that aren't in [Rabbit MQ](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ), One limitation Rabbit MQ Server does have is that the `RetryCount` for failed messages can only be `0` or `1` (in Redis MQ it can be any number).

The primary trade-off is that it requires a Rabbit MQ Broker which is an additional infrastructure dependency for environments that are already running Redis. A feature that Rabbit MQ has over Redis MQ is **Ack** support where a message is only removed from the broker if it's explicitly acknowledged on the client:

```
var responseMsg = mqClient.Get<HelloResponse>(QueueNames<HelloResponse>.In);
mqClient.Ack(responseMsg);
```